# Is there a way to know Hall of Heroes monster before hand

Tags: summoners-war

As I said in the title, I wish to know if there is a way to know the monster of the HoH before the weekend rolls around, and if so, how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming Hall of Heroes will be announced in the news (under notices) about a week before the HoH opens up.

There is no other reliable way to tell what monster will be up next.

The only thing we know in advance is the element of the upcoming HoH monster, because it has a fixed rotation (special events (like Halloween) excluded):

**Wind -> Water -> Fire -> Light -> Dark**

Since the last monster was a *Magic Knight (Wind)* we can safely assume a *Water* type will be up next in December 2017. Everything else is speculative.

Comment: Is there a way to know which weekend in the month?

Comment: @John usually the 2nd weekend every month.

Comment: Okay I thought it was the first and got confused. You were a great help